# Creating a view to show nodes with multiple aliases generated by Path Module

Tags: 6, path-aliases

I got a tough problem that I don’t even know how to start, any help would be appreciated.

I am on a D6 site.  The [Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) Module is installed and there are articles that have more than one alias because the previous admin didn't overwrite the previous alias when saving the new ones.

I am doing a data migration and the migration is grabbing the old alias and not the new one.

What I need to do is find all NIDs that have more than one Path aliases, display them, delete the old one with bulk views

When I create a view to show field Path, it only displays the current one. Any thoughts how to display both aliases or any other way to tackle this.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

As this is a one-off requirement, there's not a lot of point creating a view for this purpose, as it would mean writing code to add extra entries for path in views tables.

You will be better off writing SQL. Here's a query that'll give you what you are after:

```
SELECT src, COUNT(*) AS alias_count FROM url_alias WHERE src LIKE 'node/%' GROUP BY src HAVING alias_count > 1
```

The result will be every source path like 'node/nnn' which has more than one alias.